# NOT condition in Tridion Dreamweaver Template (DWT)

Tags: 2011, dwt

This is fairly simple:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Component.Key=='TrackingTag'" -->
 . . .
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

However, I'm stuck with reverse condition. For example in C# we usually do:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty()) //
```

So I want the Equivalent in DWT :

This was tried but Not working. condition `!(Component.Key=='TrackingTag')` always comes true.

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="!(Component.Key=='TrackingTag')" -->
```

Comment: What does @@Component.Key@@ show in your second scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Component.Key != 'TrackingTag'" -->
```

Answer (score 9):

*Siva answered how you check for inequality, but I'll chime in how to check for existence.*

The equivalent of `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Component.Key)` would probably be

```html
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Component.Key" -->
```

This condition will only pass if `Component.Key` exists **and** it has a value.

People often use that construct to ensure that a field exists/has a value, before they write the wrapper tags:

```html
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Component.Subtitle" -->
  <h3>${Component.Subtitle}</h3>
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

Comment: ok. But i need the reverse. if something doesn't exists, i need to include the lines inside. So: <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="!Component.Subtitle" --> will work ?

Comment: `!Component.Key` works to show markup for me when the field is empty. But if your schema allows multiple `Key` values, you may want a loop in addition to checking individual fields.

Answer (score 2):

Do not need to use "==" for string operand, try like below,

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Component.Key='TrackingTag'" -->
 . . .
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```